# How to display a Toast in Storage Access Framework?

Tags: android

How can I display a Toast in staorage access framework's file explorer in order to let user know that the app is reading the file and it may take a couple of seconds.

```
 public void openFile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I have tried adding Toast in this method but it didn't work.

```
private String readFileContent(Uri uri) throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream =
            getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String currentline;
    while ((currentline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(currentline + "\n");
    }
    inputStream.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Toast isn't a good idea when your users are waiting. Create a [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog) when your app is reading the file and dismiss it when the file reading is completed.